# CannotCreateTransactionException in Spring Data JPA batch process

Tags: java, mysql, spring, multithreading, hibernate

I'm trying to process about 10 million records of `MySQL DB1`, then save them to `MySQL DB2`.

I use about 50 threads to achieve this. The producer fetch `500` records from 
`MySQL DB1` one time, then put them into a queue. About 50 consumer will process them and then insert into `MySQL DB2`.

In most cases, it works fine. But for about 50 thousands records, it fails.

After I analysing the log, I found `CannotCreateTransactionException` were thrown:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:450) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
```

There are some similar questions on this site and I have tried some of them:

1. retry for 5 time after `MyRepository.saveAll()` throws exception
2. use `BasicDataSource` with a larger `maxActive` and `setValidationQuery`, `setTestOnBorrow`:

   ```
   BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
   dataSource.setMaxActive(100);
   dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   dataSource.setUrl("***");
   dataSource.setUsername("***");
   dataSource.setPassword("***");
   dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
   dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
   dataSource.setMaxActive(30);
   ```

It still does not work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched a lot and tried different solutions.

Finally, after changing my config to this, the exception does not show anymore:

```
@Bean
public DataSource poiDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setMaxActive(100);
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("**");
    dataSource.setUsername("**");
    dataSource.setPassword("**");
    dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    dataSource.setMaxActive(30);
    dataSource.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    dataSource.setMaxWait(60000);
    dataSource.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(300000);
    dataSource.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(300000);
    dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
    dataSource.setLogAbandoned(true);
    return dataSource;
}
```